# MySQL always takes wrong ID in a loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my while loop. Hard to explain but the count function always returns 1, also when it should return 0...

Here's my code:

```
$query = mysql_query("select SongID, Songtitel, artwork, duration, Upvote, SCID from tMusic order by Songtitel ASC") or die(mysql_error());
        $activeUserID = $_SESSION["user_id"];
        while ($temp = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        if (strlen($temp['Songtitel']) >= 47) {
            $ifToLong = "...";   
        } else {
            $ifToLong = "";   
        }
        $activeSongID = $temp['SongID'];
        $fistquery = mysql_query("select * from tMusicFists where SongID = ".$activeSongID." and UserID = ".$activeUserID."") or die(mysql_error());
        echo '<div class="songdiv" onclick="StreamStart('.$temp['SCID'].'); playTrack(); changeSongtitle('.$temp['Songtitel'].');">';
        echo '<div class="songimgdiv"><img class="songimg" src="'.$temp['artwork'].'" alt=""></div>';
        echo '<div class="songinfodiv">';
        echo '<div class="songtitleinfodiv"><p class="songtitleinfo">'.$activeSongID.'  '.$activeUserID.'  '.count($fistquery).'</p></div>';
        echo '<div class="songdurationdiv"><p class="durationcount">';
        $input = $temp[duration];
        $uSec = $input % 1000;
        $input = floor($input / 1000);
        $seconds = $input % 60;
        $input = floor($input / 60);
        $minutes = $input % 60;
        $input = floor($input / 60);
        echo $minutes.':'.$seconds;
        echo '</p></div>';
        if(count($fistquery) > 0) {
                echo '<div class="songratingdiv"><img class="thumbupimg" src="../images/likebrofist.png" alt=""><p class="thumbupnumber">'.$temp['Upvote'].'</p></div>';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="songratingdiv"><img class="thumbupimg" src="../images/brofist.png" alt=""><p class="thumbupnumber">'.$temp['Upvote'].'</p></div>'; 
            }

        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        }
        mysql_close();
```

I know i shouldn't use the mysql functions, but I must try it like that...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fistquery = mysql_query("select * from tMusicFists where SongID = ".$activeSongID." and UserID = ".$activeUserID."") or die(mysql_error());

count($fistquery);
```

Its not okay.... Try use mysql_num_rows($firstquery);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mysql_num_rows instead of `count`

Please use following script

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($fistquery);
if($num_rows  > 0) {
```

instead of

```
if(count($fistquery) > 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` returns either a resource or some boolean value.
Anyway, `count` of resource or boolean is `1`.

If you need number of rows - use `mysql_num_rows`.